# Can linear equations be bound by inequalities?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, graphing-functions

Graphing in Desmos,  I see many people limiting an equation by inequalities.

Like x =y (2 is smaller than x is smaller than 10) ( symbol in place of "is smaller than ")

But is this mathematically correct? Or are they doing un-mathematical thing using the app's liberty. 
I think this shouldn't be correct because if it were correct, why is there so much hype about the batman equation where complex numbers are used to limit equations?

Comment: There is nothing "unmathematical" about saying that an equation only holds if certain other conditions are tru.e

Comment: People can define whatever they want, and usually it's to serve a purpose. So yes, it's allowed.

Comment: first of all if you heard of domains for a function you would see the thing you ask as trivial . Domain definition for any function is specified while defining a function . take a simple one say y=x  then according to its definition it can represent from a point to a plane on the complex plane

Comment: But why is batman equation so complex then?  They could have just included the inequalities,  couldn't they?

Comment: Doesn't that feel like cheating because there can be a  equation without inequality representing the same thing.  So why include inequalities?  Specially when domain is taken to be the whole real number when not defined.